# Tkinter creates new main window instead of creating different window in new process

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, pyinstaller, executable

I'm writing a simple 'Ping' app, which adds 'color' identification to ping response. Like, if response failed - red screen, else green screen.

To avoid questions, i already searched my follow-up question on stackoverflow and didn't find any workable solution for my case. Some links, as example:

- [Tkinter: Launching process via multiprocessing creates not-wanted new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297892/tkinter-launching-process-via-multiprocessing-creates-not-wanted-new-window)
- [Executable using tkinter and multiprocessing creates multiple windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464661/executable-using-tkinter-and-multiprocessing-creates-multiple-windows))

Program structure looks like this:

There is two files. `main_window.py` with `main window` code and `ping_window.py` with `ping window` code. The `main window` contain `tk.Entry`s for url and some 'ping request' modifications (like `-t` or `-i`), and `tk.Button` which starts pinging (lets call it `start button`).

After pressing `start button`, I call a function, which creates and starts new `NewProcessPingWindow` class object, inherited from the `multiprocessing.process`(class is located in `ping_window.py`). In it's `run()` method i create new, separate window (let's call it `ping window`) and start `ping()` function with delivered from `main window`'s `tk.Entry`s values.

In `ping window` i show ping results every second (`ping()` function is moved into another thread, to avoid `ping window` ui freezing).

All works perfectly well in PyCharm. But when I build an executable file with `pyinstaller --onefile main_window.py`, it's becoming impossible to start `ping window` after pressing `start button`. Instead of that .exe creates new duplicate of the `main window`, without creating `ping window`. And i can continue doing this endlessly. Just every elder window will freeze after creating the new one.

Of cource I added `if __name__ == '__main__':`, but it didn't help. All works in IDE, but not with .exe.

At the end of the question
I also add code source, as long as my code is a bit long for stackoverflow posts. I didn't cut anything from example to avoid misunderstandings.

- https://pastebin.com/wTGEZqvL - main window
- https://pastebin.com/Kn0qVBM0 - ping window

P.S. I'm pretty sure that i don't see an elementary mistake, but i'm searching for 2 days and have no progress...

Comment: You claim to be able to run the code from the pastebins with no issues at all?

Comment: @Alexander yes.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Alexander windows 10. In addition, i've found the problem. i accidently deleted `multiprocessing.freezing_support()` call in `if '__name__' == '__main__;` construction. I'll add the answer

Comment: @Alexander, yes. Thanku you for your help! I also added the answer. I think, we missed our answers in a couple of minutes  Btw, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As i thought, the real reason of the wrong window-creating was my fault and inattention. I accidently deleted `multiprocessing.freezing_support()` call in `if '__name__' == '__main__:` construction. So, the `main_window` call should look like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main_window()
```

P.S. Thanks to Alexander who helped me with this problem